# Gdal: How to get a pixel's value from raster image?

Tags: raster, gdal, topography

Given a topographic raster image.

Given a pixel's coordinate in pixel/lines or geocoordinate.

**How to get it's pixel value ?**

Comment: Related to : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69129

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Get the pixels value:** gdal's [`gdallocationinfo`](http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html) allow to access a pixel's value.

> The gdallocationinfo utility provide a mechanism to query information
>   about a pixel given it's location in one of a variety of coordinate
>   systems. Several reporting options are provided.

```
$ gdallocationinfo crop.tif 50 50
Report:
  Location: (50px,50line)
  Band 1:
    Value: 73
```

To only get the value :

```
$ gdallocationinfo crop.tif 50 50 -valonly
> 73
```

Depending on geocoordinate:

```
$ gdallocationinfo crop.tif -geoloc 0.00 44.00
> 132
```

Afterwhat you may want to 1. iterate all pixels and 2. apply conditional filter.