# Topography: How to get the x,y,z coordinates of highest or lowest point/pixel of a raster GIS?

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, raster-calculator, topography

Given a .tiff topographic raster image with mountains and deep sea, I am looking for the x,y,z specifics of the highest or lowest point.

The x,y,z values being:

- altitude (z-coordinate)
- latitude (y-coordinate)
- longitude (x-coordinate)

While `gdalinfo raster.tif` would give a summary of the bounding box and the highest / lowest elevation values [(see my previous question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/gdal-highest-and-lowest-point-pixel-how-to-get-their-altitudes), and note comments below), I would like to find the elevation, latitude, longitude of the highest and/or lowest pixels of my raster.

Would be better if these values are got as isolated output integer. I think raster processing iterating on all pixels of the raster and keeping values of the z-highest point may be a good way to go.

Comment: you already asked this question, please edit your first question instead of asking a duplicate

Comment: @radouxju: This is not the same question.

Comment: @radouxju: Precision & linking was underway, now online !

Comment: IMPORTANT: these is NOT a duplicate of the other question. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/gdal-highest-and-lowest-point-pixel-how-to-get-their-altitudes just need a `gdalinfo -mm input.tif` and, amongst the long answer, is the Min/Max altitude. There is NO coordinates. Onn the other hand, this new question want the highest altitude, **and associated lat-long**. The 2 questions are different,  with this last one likely needing a completely different solution.

Comment: I agree it is not the same. However, I suggest that you should do this with something else than GDAL (e.g. QGIS) if it is not a necessity for you. Changing the tags and title will help you attract better answers.

Comment: The Comments do not form part of a Question and therefore I am unable to vote to re-open this on the basis of anything written in them.  Consequently, I recommend that you revise your Question so that, standalone, it explains why it is not a Duplicate.

Comment: Why is different is already in the question from the start: need **THREE (3) data** back : altitude (z-coordinate), longitude (x-coordinate), lattitude (y-coordinate).

Comment: Would you consider QGIS or R to get an answer to this question?

Comment: I myself need linux shell answer to fit within my project, but your answer may help others.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a scripting language like _Python_ or _R_ at least for parts of your tasks - they can easily be run within a linux shell / command line environment and are quite effective for these kind of tasks (probably more effective than pure _sh_ scripts.)

Answer (score 6):

Is Python an option?

Use [RasterIO](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) (a Python GDAL/ numpy bridge) to load the raster to NumPy array, then use [numpy.amax()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) to find the maximum value, followed by [numpy.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the row/column indices, then calculate the lat and lon from the raster extents.

Comment: +1 The same workflow would apply in `R` (with almost the same names and syntax) and in *Mathematica* (but with different names and syntax). The same *logic* applies in all raster calculator environments I can think of (Spatial Analyst, GRASS, Idrisi, Manifold) but would require more cumbersome operations.

Answer (score 2):

**I recommend using Python or R (or a GIS software), as *@Marc Pfister* has suggested.**

However, you can do it with *bash* and *gdal* only, and heavy usage of `grep`.

### First get the Min/Max values without coordinates:

Obtain the Min / Max values with `gdalinfo` or `gdalinfo -mm` like explained in [your other question about Min/Max values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/gdal-highest-and-lowest-point-pixel-how-to-get-their-altitudes). Use `grep` (and possibly some `awk`) to extract the values.

### Get their corresponding coordinates:

[Convert your tiff file to xyz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59323/convert-geotiff-to-simple-xyz-elevation-file) using `gdal_translate`. *(Beware, large file size ahead!)*

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ input.tiff /tmp/output.xyz
```

Now `grep` for the Minimum or the Maximum value. For example, if your Maximum value is 2878, type

```
cat /tmp/output.xyz | grep -E ' 2878$'
```

to get the corresponding Lat / Lon / Elevation output:
`36.2358333333333249 -0.123611111111111116 2878`

*If you are working with a float dataset, you should adapt the grep expression in order to find rounded Min/Max values.*

**That's it.**

### Alternative if you got the pixel row/column coordinates with other software:

If you don't like the *xyz* file method, you could also **first get the pixel row/column coordinates** of the Min/Max values and then convert them to the corresponding lat/lon pair with `gdaltransform`:

For example, if you found out that the maximum value is at pixel coordinates *x=12 y=300*:
`echo 12 300 | gdaltransform image.tif` will output the corresponding geo coordinate pair depending on the CRS of your source image:
`36.2358333333333249 -0.123611111111111116 0`

If you keep this final coordinate conversion as an extra step, you may be able to use some other software packages (without geospatial features) (e.g. imagemagick) or a small Python / R script to locate pixel coordinates of the the Min/Max values in a **more efficient way**.

Answer (score -1):

Since [neither `gdal_translate -stats SRTM_NE_250m.tif` , nor `gdalinfo -stats SRTM_NE_250m.tif`, nor `gdalinfo -mm SRTM_NE_250m.tif` can work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/) I think I have to iterare through the bitmap via a FOR_loop upon all pixels. The following may help.

- [Gdal: How iterate through all pixels of a raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69128)
- [Gdal: How to get a pixel's value from raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69066)

  $ gdallocationinfo crop.tif 50 50 -valonly

  > 73

Comment: Your tags include [tag:raster-calculator] and indeed a simple set of raster calculations will be far easier and more efficient than what you propose here. But which raster calculator are you using?

Comment: I'am begginer, I currently just have gdal.